# seeding one to many relationship with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I've looked through quite a few threads about seeding a one to many relationship with EF but can't seem to find the answer to what seems like a simple question.  How to do it? I have the following code where I'm trying to create an AuctionItem entity and then add AuctionImage entities to it.  But I get a null exception for auctionOne.AuctionImages on the line auctionOne.AuctionImages.Add()... Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

```
protected override void Seed(AuctionDbContext db)
        {
            var auctionOne = new AuctionItem()
            {
                AuctionComplete = string.Empty,
                AuctionDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                CurrentPrice = 2,
                EndPrice = 5,
                InitialPrice = 1,
                InitialQuantity = 1,
                LongDescription = "Long description",
                PriceDrops = 2,
                QuantityRemaining = 2,
                ReserveQuantity = 1,
                RetailPrice = 4,
                ShortDescription = "Short description",
                Title = "Auction one"                
            };

            auctionOne.AuctionImages.Add(new AuctionImage
            {
                Description = "Beautiful picture",
                Filename = "picture.jpg"
            });

            db.AuctionItems.Add(auctionOne);

            base.Seed(db);
        }
```

And here are my classes.

```
public class AuctionItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int AuctionItemID { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar"), MaxLength(256)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public decimal InitialPrice { get; set; }

        public int InitialQuantity { get; set; }

        public DateTime? AuctionDate { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(max)")]
        public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(max)")]
        public string LongDescription { get; set; }
        public decimal RetailPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal? EndPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal CurrentPrice { get; set; }
        public int PriceDrops { get; set; }
        public int QuantityRemaining { get; set; }
        public int ReserveQuantity { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "char"), MaxLength(10)]
        public string AuctionComplete { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "xml")]
        public string Metadata { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AuctionImage> AuctionImages { get; set; }
    }



public class AuctionImage
{
    [Key]
    public int AuctionImageID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuctionItem")]
    public int AuctionItemID { get; set; }

    public virtual AuctionItem AuctionItem { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar"), MaxLength(256)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(max)")]
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "xml")]
    public string MetaData { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't allocated the collection for `AuctionImages` before you are referencing it with the `Add`, which is why you get the null exception. (When the object is first created, the property will have a null value).

For seeding, it's usually just easiest to do something like:

```
      var auctionOne = new AuctionItem()
        {
            AuctionComplete = string.Empty,
            AuctionDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
            // ...
            AuctionImages = new List<AuctionImage> {
                new AuctionImage { Description="", Filename="" },
                new AuctionImage { Description="", Filename="" }
            }                  
        };
```

If you want to do it as two separate steps, just allocate the AuctionImages property as a new List<> (or other ICollection) before adding to it:

```
        var auctionOne = new AuctionItem()
        {
            // ...
            Title = "Auction one"                
        };

        auctionOne.AuctionImages = new List<AuctionImage>(); // add this
        auctionOne.AuctionImages.Add(new AuctionImage
        {
            Description = "Beautiful picture",
            Filename = "picture.jpg"
        });

        db.AuctionItems.Add(auctionOne);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks.  That is actually something I considered originally but figured that EF would have automagically created the collection for me to add items to it.  Guess not.  Thanks!